# Are Dart 1 books still relevant for learning Dart 2

Tags: dart, dart-2

I read on many places that Dart 2 is not completely backward compatible with Dart. I found a list of books that are for Dart 1.x

https://dart.dev/resources/books

Can someone with Dart 1 and Dart 2 experience tell me if this books are relevant for learning Dart 2, can I use them or I should wait for release of some Dart 2 book.

I am not sure that this is the relevant place for this type of question, but I did't found anything more suiting in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes sure it is relevant. For the language instance creation keywords like `new` and `const` have become optional to help declutter the code. They’ve made a number of small changes and done some cleanup on the dart core libraries. Nothing huge to worry about :)

Comment: Agree with this, understanding Dart 1 still helps a lot with basic concepts, syntax and ideas behind the language. It will be easy to migrate this knowledge to Dart 2